# insert query - store time

Tags: php, mysql, insert

If i have a foreach.

```
$arr = ('one','two','three','four');

foreach($arr as $val){

//query
}
```

and a column called `tmp` in table. There is possible save the exactly moment of insertion ?

With `timestamp` ,i got for all array elements  same time `(2011-10-26 18:56:31)` - equal for all.

I think there is possible detect that the element one is inserted before the element two and so on, correct ?

thanks

Comment: That is the exact moment of insertion, but you don't see the a difference because all the rows are inserted within that time (that is, after 18:56:31 and before 18:56:32).

Comment: with milliseconds, should be possible.

Comment: Milliseconds are more accurate but there's no guarantee that two rows wouldn't be inserted at the exact same millisecond.

Comment: exactly same millisecond in foreach? i think there is impossible. Each value is inserted independently. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing 4 separate queries then you could use PHPs microtime() and store that in the database.

```
$theTime = microtime(true); // 1319653454.7554
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think there is possible detect that the element one is inserted before the element two and so on, correct ?

AUTO_INCREMENT field and `microtime(true)` in PHP

Answer (score 0):

you can use [mktime](http://php.net/mktime) before and after your sql query and count how much time was taken for insert and when it was done.